# Nginx CakePHP rewrite issue

Tags: cakephp, nginx

I have been trying to get Nginx with CakePHP running with no success with regards the rewrite. I have read tons of articles and can't see anything wrong with my config file.

Nginx Webroot: `/usr/share/nginx/html`

CakePHP Installation: `/usr/share/nginx/html/cakephp`

> Error: URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

1. Help me configure it
2. I don't / can't use URL rewriting

Config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

        # Deny access to .htaccess files,
        location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
                deny  all;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is it the /doc/ location block?

Comment: Cakephp will launch its starter page with the error regarding the rewrite not configured  properly. As a result there is no css, images etc on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
```

**EDIT:**

I just looked around for cake php, it's routing is a bit different for cake php, try this instead

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$request_uri;
```

Then reload the config afterwards

Comment: Hi, I did this, and now I am receiving page cannot be displayed

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I did and still unable to rectify the problem. I have created a copy of the server on AWS. It would be great if you could take a look yourself and see where I have gone wrong. I can send you on the details on the cloned server if you are ok to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

For vhosted domain, this will work.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    rewrite ^/$ /app/webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/webroot/$1 break;

}
location /app/ {
    rewrite ^/$ /webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
}
location /app/webroot/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```